# Proving that a square can be divided into $n$ smaller squares for $n \ge 6$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction

I'm trying to prove that for all natural numbers $n \ge 6$, a square can be divided into $n$ smaller squares.

The smaller squares do not need to be of the same size.

So for induction, the base case is $P(6)$, which is that a square can be broken into $6$ squares (I can draw a picture to prove this). [six squares out of one big square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjNSm.png)

Comment: To clarify, you mean that a square of dimensions $n\times n$ can be divided into $n$ smaller squares?  That is, a $6\times6$ square can be broken into 6 smaller squares?

Comment: @anorton, the smaller squares do NOT have to be equal in size.

Comment: @Jose, please choose more specific, informative titles (I've fixed this one) rather than general titles (which are largely useless).

Comment: @Jose I understand the smaller squares don't have to be equal in size, but I want to make sure that the big square is $n\times n$.  That's what I'm assuming, but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @DannyCheuk, if you can see this, please don't make edits like that.  Changing 6 to $6$ was okay but trivial, and the other thing you did (replacing "for all natural numbers" by math symbols) only made the question *less* clear.

Comment: @anorton The size of the big square does not matter.  The smaller squares do not have to go along any specific grid lines.  The side length of a smaller square is allowed to be any real number.

Comment: I don't see how writing $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq6}$ is making the problem less clear, but anyway, cool

Comment: @Goos Ah!  That clears up quite a bit of confusion in my mind. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** You only need to do it for $6$, $7$, and $8$. For these, you need to produce explicit splittings.

But after that, anything differs by $3$ from an earlier case. and adding $3$ squares is easy, we just do the natural splitting of an existing square.

If one wants to do a formal induction,  let $n \gt 8$. Suppose the result is true for all $i$ such that $6\le i \lt n$. We want to show it holds at $n$. By the induction assumption, it holds at $n-3$. Split one of the squares of the splitting into $n-3$ squares into $4$ squares. That gives us a splitting into $n$ squares.

Comment: This is correct. But why?

Comment: So for the indiction, I need to do 3 cases, one for 6, 7, and 8.

Comment: I'm not sure what he meant, but I think that you only need to do it for $4$, $6$, $7$, $8$ and $9$. Maybe he dropped the cases $4$ and $9$ since they are easy.

Comment: @Ido, no.  Why would you need to do 4 and 9?  You can construct 6,7, and 8 and then the induction holds in general for $n \ge 6$.

Comment: @Andre, but that isn't using strong induction, is it?  Should string induction have an $n'$?

Comment: My mistake. You are correct. Still you are using the case of $4$.

Comment: @Ido: That's a matter of semantics. We are using the trivial fact that a square can be split into $4$ equal squares. Though it could be called the case $n=4$, it will cause needless confusion to call it that, since it may give the impression the induction begins at $4$. However, it does not: we can't split a square into $5$ squares.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is it possible to revise your answer to use strong induction where $n≥6$?  I can then accept it ;)

Comment: I used strong induction. From the induction assumption that the result held for all $i\lt n$, I proved it held for $n$. Maybe your version of strong induction goes from all $i\le n$ to $n+1$. The more common one goes along my lines. Now of the strong induction hypothesis, I only used the case $n-3$, but that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Or is it that you would like the symbol $n'$ used where I used $i$? If that symbol fits better the notation of your book, the change is easy to make.

Comment: Thanks, what would $p(n)$ be and $p(n+1)$, explicitly?

Comment: $p(n)$ is the assertion that a square can be divided into $n$ squares. We use strong induction, proving that if for all $i$ with $6\le i\lt n$, we have $p(i)$, then we have $p(n)$. Or if you prefer, if for all $i$ such that $6\le i\le n$, $p(i)$ holds, then $p(n+1)$ holds.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, $n'$ would be better than i