# How to cut a square on $5$ squares?

Tags: induction, combinatorial-geometry

We can cut any square on $n$ squares if $n>5$ and $n=4$.

The proof is easy by induction. Base cases $n=6,7,8$ are easy to find and then since we can cut a square on $4$ squares we get $3$ new squares, so we go from $n\to n+3$ and we are done.

But I can not find a proof that we can't cut it on $5$ squares. I suppose we should search for some contradiction, but...?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452252/proving-that-a-square-can-be-divided-into-n-smaller-squares-for-n-ge-6) is the link for $n>5$. For $n=5$ see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15181/dividing-a-square-into-5-equal-squares/15183).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: The given link for $n=5$ is about decomposing and reassembling. I think that the latter is forbidden here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book *Mathematical Olympiad Challenges*  by  Titu Andreescu and Razvan Gelca (Birkhäuser 1967) contains a proof for the case $n=5$. Here is a screenshot from page 128:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you had glue, it would be easy:

[image: 5 squares from one]

Comment: Thanks...........! +1